# Jquery Datatable is not getting recreated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am creating jquery Datatable dynamically. ColumnNames and Rows Values are coming from Server side using Ajax call. Now, I need this datatable to be reinitialized everytime, so I used property `"bDestroy": true,`  on every ajax call but after first display, DOM is getting broken. Here is my code

```
  $('#JDatadt').dataTable({
  "order": [],
  "dom": "Bfrtip",
  "buttons": ["csv", "excel", "pdf"],
  "columnDefs": [{ "className": "dt-center", "orderable": false, "width": 20 }],
  "bInfo": false,
  "paging": true,
  "processing": true,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "columns": dataObject[0].columns,
  "data": dataObject[0].data
});
```

What is getting wrong here. Please help

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @TechBreak Its giving error like `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'aDataSort' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: have you tried below provided snippet? note that it varies based on your version of data table.

Comment: @TechBreak I am using `DataTables-1.10.9`

Answer (score 0):

Datatable by default try to sort column with index 0 if not specified. 
if you don't want to sort by default with any column just add

```
"aaSorting": [[ ]] ,
```

Comment: On adding above code I got `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'mData' of undefined or null reference`. I did not downvote.

Comment: 'mData' of undefined or null reference means your columns and data are not matching. May be you have specifies a column name which is not available in Data src

Comment: Mismatch is not the issue. I am getting the Datatable if I am running it first. Issue is when I am trying to render two table using same HTML. Both tables have different number of column, one is having 6 and other 5. Any one when loaded first getting displayed fine, next load of other grid say of 6 columns or vice versa is giving the issue. for the same reason added `"bDestroy": true,` but its not working too

Comment: Are you trying to add 2 tables in $('#JDatadt') id.

Comment: yes, On button click. I want one of the two table to be displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128140/discussion-between-ashish451-and-lara).

Comment: Could you please come on the chat link. I am waiting there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can destroy table by using fnDestroy() function of datatable. it will surely works for you.